# How to fetch the pubtitle in the ditamap using xsl expressions

Tags: xml, xslt, dita, dita-ot

For fetching the pubtitle value in the below ditamap using the xsl expressions
MY Input XML Dita map file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pubmap
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.sam.doctypes:dita:pubmap" "pubmap.dtd">
<pubmap xml:lang="en-US">
  <pubtitle>
    <mainpubtitle outputclass="book">Sample Word</mainpubtitle>
  </pubtitle>
  <topicref href="topics/topic_1.dita">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>Ram-Files-Raj (RFR)</navtitle>
      <metadata/>
    </topicmeta>
  </topicref>
  <topicref href="topics/topic_2.dita">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>Files-Sampletitle (FST)</navtitle>
      <metadata/>
    </topicmeta>
  </topicref>
</pubmap>
```

My topic_1.dita file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.sam.doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Ram-Files-RajRFR"><title>Ram-Files-Raj (RFR)</title></topic>
```

My topic_2.dita file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.sam.doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_2" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Files-SampletitleFST"><title>Files-Sampletitle (FST)</title></topic>
```

for topic title fetching i am using the xsl variable as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="maintitle"><xsl:apply-templates select="/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]" mode="text-only"/></xsl:variable>
```

As like above format i want to fetch the diamap main title of this element mainpubtitle outputclass="book" value.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

```
<xsl:variable name="maintitle">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[contains(@outputclass, 'book')]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Or if you don't want to use that, maybe this is okay for you:

```
<xsl:variable name="maintitle">
   <xsl:value-of select="//mainpubtitle[@outputclass = 'book']/text()"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Hi @barbwire, If i am using first one then dita ot epub plugin conversion error displaying as "
Engine name: DITA-OT
Severity: fatal
Description: Too many nested apply-templates calls. The stylesheet may be looping.
Start location: 3896:0"
for second one its not fetching the text

Comment: Well, with first one you would need for example own  template when using that. Like that for example: <xsl:template match="mainpubtitle">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template> . Second one, don't know what is wrong without seeing the whole xsl. These were just examples, which should work with simple usage (tested them in my machine with your example file).

Comment: Thank you @barbwire first one working fine if i have used outside the template.